# Hive Hadoop : Need to LOAD data into a table based on conditions on the input file

Tags: insert, hive

I am new to Hadoop Hive and have just started to do basic querying in hive.
My intention is I have an input text file (which has large number of records per line). The format of the file is something like this:

```
1;23;0;;;;1;3;2;1;1;4;5;6;;;;

1;43;6;;;;1;3;2;1;1;4;5;5;;;;

1;53;7;;;;1;3;2;1;1;4;5;2;;;;
```

(Each integer before a "`;`" has a meaning which I am intending to put it in Hive table as column names - and each line contains about 400 fields)

So for inserting this I have created a table "test" - using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (field1 INT, field2 INT, field3 INT, field4 INT, ... field390 INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\073";
```

And I load my text file with the records using the LOAD query as below:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/test.txt'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test;
```

For now all the fields are getting inserted into the table upto 50 fields accurately. Later I have mismatches.

What I have in my format of input is - at 50th field in the test.txt I have a INT number which decides the number of fields to take following the field.

**Example:**

50th field: **2**   -> Hive has to take the next **2*10** field INT values and insert in the table.

50th field: **1**   -> Hive has to take the next **1*10** field INT values and insert in the table. And the rest 10 fields can be set NULL.

(The maximum value of 50th field is **2** - so I have reserved 2*10 fields for this in the table)

After 50th+(2*10) fields , the data should be read normally in the sequence as it did before the 50th field.

Do we have a way in which we can have a condition on the input so that the data gets inserted accordingly in Hive.

A help may be appreciated. Need a solution which will not guide me to pre-process the test.txt and then supply to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to answer it at http://www.knowbigdata.com/page/hive-hadoop-need-load-data-table-based-conditions-input-file#comment-85

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sandeep. I have started using PIG for processing the input for sometime now. Will definitely give a try to Approach 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause in Hive.

First load data into Hive raw table or HDFS, then again create table and load data based on where clause. 
Means:

SELECT * FROM table_reference
WHERE name like "%venu%"
GROUP BY City;

Resource: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select